# Dynamic Range and one static Item to a ComboBox via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, combobox

I have this code:

```
With Sheet1.Shapes("comboBox1").ControlFormat
    .ListFillRange = "namedRange"
    .AddItem "1.Item"
End With
```

But after that, just "1.Item" is in my `Combo-Box` and the dynamic range don't appear at all.

How can I add **one** `Item` and my `Range` to the `Combo-Box`?

---

**EDIT**

The dynamic `range` would work if I delete `.AddItem`:

```
With Sheet1.Shapes("comboBox1").ControlFormat
    .ListFillRange = "namedRange"
End With
```

My Question is if there is a possibility to combine those to not in a range, but rather separated from each other.

---

Thank you very much in advance for your answers...

Comment: Why not add the extra item into your range?

Comment: That was my Idea too, but I want to know if there is a better way for my first attempt. And I can't add it to my current range because I use this range for more than just that Combo-Box. So I need to make a new range... and that would be (kind of) useless...

Comment: @holyFackel is your ComboBox a `User_Form` type ? or `ActiveX` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado a User_Form ...

Comment: but placed in a sheet ? or inside a `user_form` ?

Comment: Oh, wait... it's not an ActiveX Control, it's a Form Control placed in a normal Sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your post correctly, you want to add another Item to the items in your "namedRange" and show all these items in your worksheet ComboBox (which is actually a drop-down in your worksheet).

(modify "Sheet2" to your sheet's name).

```
Sub PopulateCombo_fromArray()

Dim ComboArray As Variant

'clear Combo-Box from previous runs >> modify "Sheet2" to your sheet's name
Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems

' reading the NamedRange into a 1-dimension array
ComboArray = Application.Transpose(Range("namedRange").Value)

ReDim Preserve ComboArray(UBound(ComboArray))
' add another element to the array (outside the "namedRange")
ComboArray(UBound(ComboArray)) = "1.Item"

' populate "ComboBox1" with array
Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes("comboBox1").ControlFormat.List = ComboArray

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I make the "1.Item" to ListIndex **1**?

Comment: @holyFackel  what do u mean ? What do you want to do with the "1.Item" ?

Answer (score 1):

Must you use "Shapes"?

if not, you can fill a combobox with a named range like this :

```
With Sheet1.ComboBox1
    .List = Application.Transpose(Range("namedRange"))
    .AddItem "1.Item"
End With
```

Comment: Yes, digging the range out into a variant array is the first step, then redimension the array for an extra element, populate with the extra item and use as list source.